# IOS: adMob two type of advertising

Tags: ios, admob, ads

In my app I want to insert a banner 768x90 and a interstitial, but when I add my app I can choose only an option (or banner or interstitial) that give me only a unit-ID... is not possible use inside an app interstitial and a banner?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using an AdMob publisher ID, it can work for both banners and interstitials. If you created a mediation placement ID, it should only be used for the ad type you specified. You can create a second mediation placement with the other ad type, and use one placement for the leaderboard banner, and the other for interstitials.

Comment: ah ok, then with my "editor ID" (publisher ID) I can put it inside my code for both banner and interstitials? and it work fine? and what are the difference to use a publisher ID and a mediation placement ID?

Comment: A mediation ID is what you get if you set up a mediation placements on mediation.admob.com. It allows you to configure multiple ad networks if you want to allocate your traffic to more than one network. You can learn more about it [here](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2413211?hl=en). An AdMob publisher ID is 15 characters long starting with `a14` or `a15`. A mediation placement ID is 16 hexadecimal characters.